# Javascript regex replace

Tags: regex

I have a langauge dropdown, and a javascript function which changes the page to the corresponding language selected. I need help on my regex replace:

For example, I would like this URL to turn into this url:
http://localhost:7007/en/Product/Detail/1038
http://localhost:7007/fr/Product/Detail/1038

```
  function languageChange(sender) {
    var lang = $(sender).val();

    var target = window.location.href;
    target = target.replace(/(http:\/\/.*?)([a-zA-Z]{2})(.*$)/gim, '$1' + lang + '$3');


    window.location = target;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your URL always the same structure? If so, you may not need a regex at all. Split the url at each "/", replace index 3, then join your array back to together with "/".

Here is a code sample:

```
function changeLanguage(url, newLang) {
    var url = url.split('/');
    url[3] = newLang;
    return url.join('/');
}
changeLanguage('http://localhost:7007/en/Product/Detail/1038','Fr');
```

Note: I originally wrote "splice" instead of "join" in my response. Join is the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that processes any number of URLs within a string, and replaces the language part (the first part of path), only if exists and is from 2 to 4 chars long:

```js
function changeLanguage(text, lang) {
    return text.replace(
        /\b(\w+:\/\/[^\/]+\/)[A-Z]{2,4}(?=[\/\s]|$)/gim,
        '$1' + lang);
}
```

**Edit:** Converted to function format.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
target =
    target.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^/]+)\/?([^/]*)(.*)/gi, '$1/' + lang + '$3');
```

if e.g. `lang='fr'` then `target` holds `http://localhost:7007/fr/Product/Detail/1038` value;

Comment: This regex: `/(https?:\/\/[^/]+\/?)([^/]+)(.*)/gim` doesn't work if the URL path is empty. (The regex does not require a `/`) Given the URL: `http://localhost:7007` this returns `http://localhost:700fr`.